# Linq Queries - How to join the below two group by queries? On Course ID

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to join two group by queries to get one results set.

```
var query = from PP in _db.paymentPlans
            join APP in _db.Applications on PP.applicationID equals APP.ApplicationId
            join C in _db.Courses on APP.courseID equals C.courseID
            where PP.active == true && APP.agentID == agentID
            orderby C.courseID ascending
            group new {C,PP} by new {C.courseID} into totalRecievable
            // Query 1

            from PD in _db.paymentDetails
            join PP in _db.paymentPlans on PD.paymentPlanID equals PP.paymentPlanID
            join APP in _db.Applications on PP.applicationID equals APP.ApplicationId
            join C in _db.Courses on APP.courseID equals C.courseID
            where PP.active == true && APP.agentID == agentID
            orderby C.courseID ascending
            group new { C,PD } by new { C.courseID, C.cricosCode, C.courseName } into paymentsCourseWise
           // Query 2

            select new PdPpAppCourseModel
            {
                courseID = paymentsCourseWise.Key.courseID,
                cricosCode = paymentsCourseWise.Key.cricosCode,
                courseName = paymentsCourseWise.Key.courseName,
                totalAmount = totalRecievable.Sum(x => x.PP.totalAmount),
                paidAmount = paymentsCourseWise.Sum(x => x.PD.paidAmount)
            }).ToList();
```

Total about is taken from query 1 as it should group in payment plan(PP) level.

Answer (score 0):

You can only combine enumerations of the same type, you could project both to a common class and then concatenate them:

```
var result1 = db1.table.Where(a=>a.value>0).Select( x=> new Foo() { //set props });
var result2 = db2.table.Where(a=>a.value>0).Select( x=> new Foo() { //set props });
var resultSum = result1.Concat(result2);
```

Similarly you can apply this in your code and join this two groups.

Comment: Here the problem is instead of joining the new column, two queries gives two record sets separately. Any other way to resolve this?

Comment: Another solution is also exist but for that you have to try first.